# HTML5 Canvas Change Image Z-Index

Tags: javascript, html, image, html5-canvas

I am creating an HTML5 Canvas game and I came to a problem, is there a way to change the image layering order? Something like Z-Index in normal HTML? I can't really put it into words so I'll upload an image of what's happening right now.

[image]

What I want is the grey part to cover all the other images inside the canvas. The scope already has transparency so it should render whatever is behind it but I don't want to render what is on the grey part. Is there a way to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to make multiple layers is by using multiple canvases and stacking them over each other with CSS positioning.

When you want to use only one canvas, you can start your drawing loop with erasing your whole canvas and then redrawing the whole scene from back to front. When you use [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame), you shouldn't even have any flickering, because the rendering engine of the web browser will take care of that.

Another option could be to use [globalCompositeOperation](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/advanced/html5-canvas-global-composite-operations-tutorial/). It allows you to mask what you draw with what is already drawn. When you use the mode `destination-over`, you will only draw on pixels where nothing else is drawn.

Comment: I already have the flickering part solved, how would I layer two canvases though? I mean, I have a mouse coordinate "listener" every time the mouse moves, would it work on both canvases?

Comment: @user2673553 A mouse-listener would only work on the top-canvas, so you need to catch all input-events there. But that does not mean that that event-handler can't draw on any other canvas.

Comment: @user2673553 To stack HTML elements like canvases on top of each other, add `position:absolute` to their CSS style.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I was actually thinking about that last night and I have one last question... The Navigational Bar up top already has a position of absolute, how would I make the navigational bar and the canvases not overlap eachother? Would it work if I wrapped all the canvases with a div and only set the absolute position on the canvases but not the div?

Comment: @user2673553 `position:absolute` always orients itself after the next parent which is not absolute itself. So when you put all the canvases into a div with no special positioning, they will be oriented in that div.

Answer (score 1):

You can manage this using Compositing in HTML5 Canvas drawing API

http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/2dcontext/html5_canvas/#compositing

With examples

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/canvas_composition.htm

Comment: Thank you for answering, this is a good source although I think Philipp's answer was more of what I was looking for. I will keep the website in my bookmarks though for later reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can append the canvas to a  element instead of to the document body, like this:
Let your div have an id, like this:

```
<div id="myDiv1"></div>
```

Then have another div with a different id:

```
<div id="myDiv2"></div>
```

These two should be peers, meaning one is not nested inside the other.
Now you can position these any way you like, and give them z-index properties of your choice, either directly on the div elements or externally and referenced in.
Now you have, say:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="z-index:1"></div>  
<div id="myDiv2" style="z-index:2"></div>
```

If these are positioned on top of each other, then myDiv2 will appear on top of myDiv1.
Now finally, in Javascript you can append a canvas element to either div (or a different one in each), like this:

```
var c = document.createElement("canvas");  
var myCanvas1 = document.getElementById('myDiv1');  
myCanvas1.appendChild(c);  
var d = document.createElement("canvas");  
var myCanvas2 = document.getElementById('myDiv2');  
myCanvas2.appendChild(d);
```

and then continue with the contents of the canvases. Finally your can control
the stacking through Javascript by changing the z-indexes of the corresponding container divs. For example, given the setup above, you can do the following Javascript statement, in some Javascript function of your choice, to put myCanvas1 on top of myCanvas2:

```
document.getElementById('myCanvas1').style.zIndex = 3;
```